# Dynamically print results received with json in cards on html page with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

My aim is to dynamically create multiple cards using javascript for which I am obtaining data via JSON.

Here is sample data that would appear in JSON.

```
var appStatus = 
[  
   {  
      "app":"Application A",
      "category":"Overall Status",
      "status":"1"
   },
   {  
      "app":"Application A",
      "category":"System Status",
      "status":"2"
   },
   {  
      "app":"Application B",
      "category":"Overall Status",
      "status":"1"
   },
   {  
      "app":"Application B",
      "category":"Overall Status",
      "status":"2"
   }
]
```

Status 1 / 2 / 3 is for Green / Yellow / Red, that I can modify within the javascript. Is there a way to suffice this exercise without creating a table in the card? Or feel free to share any other way, but this need to be displayed as cards.

```css
.card-body {
 padding: .40rem 0.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.card-title {
 margin-top: 0.50rem;
  margin-bottom: .1rem;
  
}

.custom-cards{
 height:250px;
}

.card-header {
 padding: .40rem 0.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #01233F;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5 mb-3">
    <div class="card h-90 text-left">
    <div class="card-body custom-cards">
    <h4><div class="card-header">Application A<img alt="Green" align="right" src="http://nautilus.baruch.sc.edu/twiki_dmcc/pub/Main/ObsCatalog/green_operational_icon.png"width="32" height="32"></div></h4> 
    <h5><div class="card-body">System Availability<img alt="Red" align="right" src="http://nautilus.baruch.sc.edu/twiki_dmcc/pub/Main/ObsCatalog/red_offline_icon.png"width="32" height="32"></div></h5>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-5 mb-3">
    <div class="card h-90 text-left">
    <div class="card-body custom-cards">
    <h4><div class="card-header">Application B<img alt="Green" align="right" src="http://nautilus.baruch.sc.edu/twiki_dmcc/pub/Main/ObsCatalog/green_operational_icon.png"width="32" height="32"></div></h4>
    <h5><div class="card-body">System Availability<img alt="Yellow" align="right" src="http://nautilus.baruch.sc.edu/twiki_dmcc/pub/Main/ObsCatalog/yellow_planned_icon.png"width="32" height="32"></div></h5>
    <h5><div class="card-body">More Options<img alt="Green" align="right" src="http://nautilus.baruch.sc.edu/twiki_dmcc/pub/Main/ObsCatalog/green_operational_icon.png"width="32" height="32"></div></h5>
    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"><div style="text-align: left"></div></h6>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Next, I used some html and my css skills to generate static cards, but my attempts are terribly failing when I am trying to create multiple cards dynamically with javascript. Sharing what I coded for static html cards and CSS for this task.

I am also attaching a screenshot of my static created page. Thanks for taking your time, to go through this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You gotta check out `document.createElement('div')`

document.createElement() is a native javascript method, this will dynamically generate an html element of your choosing. You can then append this element to any parent you like. You can loop through your objects like

```
function renderCards(){
  for(var i = 0; i < appStatus.length; i++){
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'card-body';
        div.innerHTML = appStatus[i].app;
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
  }
}
```

You can add appendChild() to any element that you want to use as a parent for your *data cards*. You need to modify this script to make it jive with your objectives though, as this is only a code concept

But this is the exact dynamic-ness that you are looking for -- in standard Javascript fashion.